# How to use Rcpp to do numerical integration in C++ within R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, numerical-integration

I was wondering how `Rcpp` could be used to perform numerical integration by calling C++ in R. My current setup takes a really long time and is highly error prone.

I think I need something better than default R numerical integration package. Would doing numerical integration in C++ within R solve these problems?

```
funk <- function(x,b) { 10^b * exp(-x/10) }

lambda <- function(y,k) { exp(-k*y) }

funk1 <- function(y,x,xb,b,k) { 
funk(x-xb-y,b) *exp(- integrate(lambda, lower=0, upper = y, k=k)$value) }

funk2 <-function(x,xb,b,k) { 
integrate(funk1, lower= 0, upper=x-xb, x=x,xb=xb, b=b,k=k)$value }

funk2_vc <- Vectorize(funk2)
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have a lot easier time using `RcppNumerical` with `Rcpp` (and yes, it would make it faster).

The code is a port of [NumericalIntegration](https://github.com/tbs1980/NumericalIntegration), which combines relevant parts of Quantlib and a few other C++ libraries like [LibLBFGS](https://github.com/chokkan/liblbfgs).

Here's [a nice tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/rcppnumerical-numerical-integration-and-optimization-with-rcpp/) to get you started.

To compute integration of a function, first define a function inherited from
the `Func` class:

```
class Func
{
public:
    virtual double operator()(const double& x) const = 0;
    virtual void   operator()(double* x, const int n) const
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            x[i] = this->operator()(x[i]);
    }
};
```

The tutorial and package documentation should be enough to suit your needs, but if you need more help check out the documentation for the C++ library `NumericalIntegration`.

Comment: Good answer (though technically, it is not RcppNumerical _instead of_ Rcpp but rather _with_ as the latter is used with the former). There is another quadrature package using Rcpp that I now of:  fastGHQuad.  But RcppNumerical does look like a good bet.

Comment: @Hack-R Thanks! I am now hooked on to the tutorial. Hopefully would soon be able to use `Rcpp` for numerical integration within R.